# SpaCy questions about lists of lists in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, spacy

I think part of my issue has to do with spaCy and part has to do with not understanding the most elegant way to work within python itself.

I am uploading a txt file in python, tokenizing it into sentences and then tokenizing that into words with nltk:

```
sent_text = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
tokenized_text = [nltk.word_tokenize(x) for x in sent_text]
```

That gives me a list of lists, where each list within the main list is a sentence of tokenized words. So far so good.

I then run it through SpaCy:

```
text = nlp(unicode(tokenized_text))
```

Still a list of lists, same thing, but it has all the SpaCy info.

This is where I'm hitting a block. Basically what I want to do is, for each sentence, only retain the nouns, verbs, and adjectives, and within those, also get rid of auxiliaries and conjunctions. I was able to do this earlier by creating a new empty list and appending only what I want:

```
sent11 = []
  for token in sent1:
    if (token.pos_ == 'NOUN' or token.pos_ == 'VERB' or token.pos_ =='ADJ') and (token.dep_ != 'aux') and (token.dep_ != 'conj'):
      sent11.append(token)
```

This works fine for a single sentence, but I don't want to be doing it for every single sentence in a book-length text.

Then, once I have these new lists (or whatever the best way to do it is) containing only the pieces I want, I want to use the "similarity" function of SpaCy to determine which sentence is closest semantically to some other, much shorter text that I've done the same stripping of everything but nouns, adj, verbs, etc to.

I've got it working when comparing one single sentence to another by using:

```
sent1.similarity(sent2)
```

So I guess my questions are

1) What is the best way to turn a list of lists into a list of lists that only contain the pieces I want?

and

2) How do I cycle through this new list of lists and compare each one to a separate sentence and return the sentence that is most semantically similar (using the vectors that SpaCy comes with)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on or reword 2? Do you have one sentence you are comparing this entire book to or two books of the same length or something else?

Comment: I'm collecting user input and comparing that against each sentence in a book-length text. It may be one sentence or a few sentences, it won't be more than a short paragraph. I've been able to compare a single sentence to a paragraph using SpaCy, so I don't anticipate the difference in length being a problem...

Comment: Eventually I want to get to the point where I am comparing the user input to a bunch of different books, and then once it finds the best match, finding the closest matching sentence WITHIN that book, but I'm saving that for later.

Comment: Is the user input one sentence or multiple?

Comment: It will probably be multiple, but may be just one. From my understanding, though, it shouldn't matter because SpaCy treats anything more than a token in a similar way (averaging the vectors of each word), so would there be any difference if it's one sentence vs more than one?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a bunch of questions here so I'm going to try to break them down.

1. Is nearly duplicating a book-length amount of text by appending each word to a list bad?
2. How can one eliminate or remove elements of a list efficiently?
3. How can one compare a sentence to each sentence in the book where each sentence is a list and the book is a list of sentences.

Answers:

1. Generally yes, but on a modern system it isn't a big deal. Books are text which are probably just UTF-8 characters if English, otherwise they might be Unicode. A UTF-8 character is a byte and even a long book such as [War and Peace](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2600) comes out to under 3.3 Mb. If you are using chrome, firefox, or IE to view this page your computer has more than enough memory to fit a few copies of it into ram.
2. In python you can't really.

You can do removal using:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
del l[-2]
print(l)
[1,2,4]
```

but in the background python is copying every element of that list over one. It is not recommended for large lists. Instead using a [dequeue](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which implements itself as a doublely-linked-list has a bit of extra overhead but allows for efficient removal of elements in the middle.

If memory is an issue then you can also use [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)) wherever possible. For example you could probably change:

```
tokenized_text = [nltk.word_tokenize(x) for x in sent_text]
```

which creates a list that contains tokens of the entire book, with

```
tokenized_text = (nltk.word_tokenize(x) for x in sent_text)
```

which creates a generator that yields tokens of the entire book. Generators have almost no memory overhead and instead compute the next element as they go.

3. I'm not familiar with SpaCy, and while the question fits on SO you're unlikely to get good answers about specific libraries here.

From the looks of it you can just do something like:

```
best_match = None
best_similarity_value = 0
for token in parsed_tokenized_text:
    similarity = token.similarity(sent2)
    if similarity > best_similarity_value:
        best_similarity_value = similarity
        best_match = token
```

And if you wanted to check against multiple sentences (non-consecutive) then you could put an outer loop that goes through those:

```
for sent2 in other_token_list:
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! Because I'm still not very knowledgeable, I have a few follow-up questions.

Comment: 1)  So you're saying, after I tokenize a book-length text into a list of sentences of tokenized words, it's relatively fine to create a new list of lists and append just the stuff I'm interested in? I guess I'm not totally sure how I would do that when I'm dealing with more than one sentence. So, say I have War and Peace tokenized into sentences and words. How would I then go through & automate the process of creating a new empty list for each sentence & appending only the stuff I want (nouns, verbs, adjs) from each original sentence to each new empty list?

Comment: 2) Can you describe a bit more about the outer loop you menioned when investigating similarity? I'm not quite sure I understand what adding that on to the code above it will do.

Comment: for 1: I'm saying that you are using sizes of data that are non-trivial but small enough that you don't need to worry about using too much so appending is just fine.
for 2: you put that in front of the loop before the inner loop and it will check against all the sentences that the user had entered. You'll need to change the inside loop a little so you don't overwrite best_match every time but you can use a similar idea.

Comment: Thanks, for 1, I still don't understand _how_ I would do this process, though